# How to validate date in XML with perl

Tags: xml, perl

I want to validate date which is coming from XML. 
e.g. 
      2014-03-11 #yyyy-mm-dd format

I want to ensure that it should be in a same format. I am using this XML inside perl.
Is there any way to do it the same. Any help would be appreciated.
I know XML::Checker module but that does not serve my purpose.

Comment: What sort of verification do you want to do? Note that it is generally impossible to detect the difference between `yyyy-mm-dd` and `yyyy-dd-mm` format dates, because `2014-02-12` could be either.

Comment: If you "use the xml in Perl", does that mean you have its contents in some kind of variable inside Perl at some point? If so, use regex?

Comment: Use regex like `my ($y, $m, $d) = $strdate =~ /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/`.

Comment: I tried with this one : /^20\d{2}\-[01-12]\-[1-31]$/
but it wont work

Comment: Is there any options to validate month & date i.e. month 1-12 and date 1-31

Comment: @Borodin, luckily I've never met anybody who tried using yyyy-dd-mm as a date format.

Answer (score 2):

[Types::XSD](https://metacpan.org/pod/Types%3a%3aXSD) allows you to validate data against any XML Schema built-in data type.

```
use Types::XSD qw(is_Date);

for my $date (qw( 2000-02-28 2000-02-29 2000-02-30 )) {
   printf(
      "%s - %s\n",
      is_Date($date) ? "ok" : "not ok",
      $date,
   );
}
```

Comment: I want to validate using /^20?\d{2}\-0?(:?[1-9]|10|11|12)\-\d{2}$/) expression. Can you please help me in this approach

Comment: I think 0?(:?[1-9]|10|11|12) is not feasible approach

Comment: If you just want a regular expression, you could try `$date =~ /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})(??{ $2 <= 12 && $3 <= 31 ? "" : "(*FAIL)" })$/` -- it's not perfect; it allows the 31st of February for example -- but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Well.. I have created alternative as,                  


if ($dateVal =~ /^20?\d{2}\-0?(:?[1-9]|10|11|12)\-(\d{2})$/)
{
     if ($2 <= 31){ print "All DD's are correct\n";}
     else {print "Please verify the DD again !\n"}
}

Comment: `$dateVal = "2012-012-٦٧"` passes that test.